# Difference between two dates in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Calculating the difference between two dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates)
>   [What’s the best way to calculate date difference in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript)

How can I find difference between two dates in JavaScript?

Comment: Take your pick on the dupes -- http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=date+difference+javascript.  I went with [Calculating the difference between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates)

Comment: I thought [327429](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript) was a closer dup.

Answer (score 1):

```
 return date1 - date2;
 // returns the number of microseconds between the two `Date`s.
```

Comment: @OP: Yes, really, it's *that* easy. :-) The result is a number, in milliseconds. You have to be careful with historical dates, though, Javascript's Date object doesn't handle the Gregorian change in 1582. For contemporary dates, though, it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

Comment: No link-only answers, please. SO should stand on its own; external links can disappear, get renamed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

http://www.mcfedries.com/JavaScript/DaysBetween.asp

Comment: No link-only answers, please. SO should stand on its own; external links can disappear, get renamed, etc.

Comment: aa ok, my bad. I will post the main idea from the link

Comment: but something like this: 
`
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--

function days_between(date1, date2) {

    // The number of milliseconds in one day
    var ONE_DAY = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24

    // Convert both dates to milliseconds
    var date1_ms = date1.getTime()
    var date2_ms = date2.getTime()

    // Calculate the difference in milliseconds
    var difference_ms = Math.abs(date1_ms - date2_ms)
    
    // Convert back to days and return
    return Math.round(difference_ms/ONE_DAY)

}

//-->
</script>
`