# How to calculate number of days between two dates in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I am having two dated in dd/mm/yyyy format. How to calculate the number of days between these two dates in javascript/jquery.

Example: Fom date is 20/06/2000, to date is 16/08/2011

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/327429/whats-the-best-way-to-calculate-date-difference-in-javascript

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates

Comment: @vinothini You will need to accept more answers before asking any more questions.

Comment: See related section of this question page. You will find similar questions.

Answer (score 8):

Simple code

```
var Date1 = new Date (2008, 7, 25);
var Date2 = new Date (2009, 0, 12);
var Days = Math.round((Date2.getTime() - Date1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
```

Comment: This fails when crossing from non-daylight savings time to daylight savings time.  It will end up being one day less than it should be.  The calculation (Date2.getTime() - Date1.... comes up to be (for example) 5.96, which using Math.floor becomes 5, when it should be 6.

Comment: Use Math.round instead.
See another stackoverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2627493/12942220

Answer (score 4):

```
var date1 = new Date(2000, 6, 20);
var date2 = new Date(2011, 8, 16);

var one_day = 1000*60*60*24; //Get 1 day in milliseconds

var days = Math.ceil( (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime() ) / one_day);
```

`Math.ceil` to round up, `Math.floor` to round down.

http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/datedifference.shtml

Answer (score 3):

```
t1="10/10/2006";
t2="15/10/2006";

//Total time for one day
var one_day=1000*60*60*24;  //Here we need to split the inputed dates to convert them into standard format for further execution
var x=t1.split("/");     
var y=t2.split("/");   //date format(Fullyear,month,date) 

var date1=new Date(x[2],(x[1]-1),x[0]);

// it is not coded by me,but it works correctly,it may be useful to all

var date2=new Date(y[2],(y[1]-1),y[0])
var month1=x[1]-1;
var month2=y[1]-1;

//Calculate difference between the two dates, and convert to days

_Diff=Math.ceil((date2.getTime()-date1.getTime())/(one_day));
```