# How do i find the difference between two dates using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to get reaming days to go particular date so i am trying to detection of particular date with today date. but this not working here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/sJueG/)   If the date is next month 27 how can i get remaining days to go

```
    var date2=new Date();
    var date1=27/5/2012;
    var diff = date1.getDate()-date2.getDate();
    var date_reaming = diff.getDate();
    document.write(date_reaming + 'days to go');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542938/how-do-i-get-the-number-of-days-between-two-dates-in-jquery

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the answer, i found this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates/1440718#1440718)  my js-fiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshpattu/kd3Sg/2/)

```
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth();/* Returns the month (from 0-11) */
var curr_month_plus= curr_month+1; /* because if the month is  4 it will show output 3 so we have to add +1 with month*/ 
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
function dstrToUTC(ds) {
    var dsarr = ds.split("/");
     var mm = parseInt(dsarr[0],10);
     var dd = parseInt(dsarr[1],10);
     var yy = parseInt(dsarr[2],10);
     return Date.UTC(yy,mm-1,dd,0,0,0); }
    function datediff(ds1,ds2) {
     var d1 = dstrToUTC(ds1);
     var d2 = dstrToUTC(ds2);
     var oneday = 86400000;
     return (d2-d1) / oneday;    }
    var a =curr_month_plus+ '/' + curr_date + '/' + curr_year;
    var b;   
    b = "5/26/2012";
    document.write(+datediff(a,b)+" day(s)<br>");
```

Answer (score 16):

Your code

```
date1=27/5/2012
```

Actually means 27 divided by 5 divided by 2012. It is equivalent to writing

```
date1 = 0.0026838966202783303
```

date1 will be a number, and this number has no `getDate` method.

If you declared them as actual date objects instead

```
var date2 = new Date(2012, 3, 19);
var date1 = new Date(2012, 4, 27);
```

You would be able to perform

```
var diff = date1 - date2;
```

This would give you the difference in milliseconds between the two dates.

From here, you could calculate the number of days like so:

```
var days = diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
```

Answer (score 8):

```
function getDateDiff(date1, date2, interval) {
    var second = 1000,
    minute = second * 60,
    hour = minute * 60,
    day = hour * 24,
    week = day * 7;
    date1 = new Date(date1).getTime();
    date2 = (date2 == 'now') ? new Date().getTime() : new Date(date2).getTime();
    var timediff = date2 - date1;
    if (isNaN(timediff)) return NaN;
    switch (interval) {
    case "years":
        return date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear();
    case "months":
        return ((date2.getFullYear() * 12 + date2.getMonth()) - (date1.getFullYear() * 12 + date1.getMonth()));
    case "weeks":
        return Math.floor(timediff / week);
    case "days":
        return Math.floor(timediff / day);
    case "hours":
        return Math.floor(timediff / hour);
    case "minutes":
        return Math.floor(timediff / minute);
    case "seconds":
        return Math.floor(timediff / second);
    default:
        return undefined;
    }
}

console.log(getDateDiff('19/04/2012', '27/5/2012', 'days'));
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery has not built-in date management functions. Try with: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 3):

I think you can subtract it:

```
var date2 = new Date(2012, 3, 19); // 1st argument = year, 2nd = month - 1 (because getMonth() return 0-11 not 1-12), 3rd = date
var date1 = new Date(2012, 4, 27);
var distance = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
distance = Math.ceil(distance / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24); // convert milliseconds to days. ceil to round up.
document.write(distance);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please understand what jQuery is made for.

> jQuery is a fast and concise JavaScript Library that simplifies **HTML document traversing**, **event handling**, **animating**, and **Ajax interactions** for rapid web development.

You want to use *basic* Javacript or as Juan G. Hurtado states another library like **momentjs**.