# javascript: how to validate two dates for one month in javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to compare two dates for exactly one month. I used the code below for the validation. Its working for this case:

from `Date:1/5/2013` to `Date:1/6/2013`

but not working if we consider February month, e.g.:

`fromDate:28/2/2013;` `toDate:31/3/2013;`

Can you let me know the solution?

I tried the code below ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates?rq=1)), but it's not working.

```
var fromDate = new Date(document.getElementById("Billing_From").value);
var toDate = new Date(document.getElementById("Billing_To").value);
fromDate.setMonth( fromDate.getMonth() + 1 );
if((fromDate-toDate) !=0)
{
    alert("Please limit the date range to 1 month.");
}
```

Comment: What's the correct behaviour you want? Are you saying it should be - for example - from 28 Feb to 28 March? But from 31 March to 30 April (because there isn't a 31 April)?

Comment: You can try downloading datejs: http://www.datejs.com/ and then use the `isAfter` or `isBefore` methods to check your date range.

Answer (score 0):

Keep the following in mind.

1. The default format is MM/dd/yyyy.
2. In Javascript Date months are from 0(Jan) to 11(Dec).

This code is for comparing same dates of adjacent months. Example - 15th Feb, 2013 and 15th March, 2013.

What is you exact definition of month ?

Comment: a month means 15th Feb 2013 to 14th March 2013