# Compare time between datetime+millisecond and currentime

Tags: javascript, date

I'm trying to add `duration` for each token. For now each token has duration 3600000ms(1hour), and maybe it will change base on term and conditions.
I create the duration using this:

```
global.duration = 60*60*1000;
```

and I also have a column called createdAt, default from sequelize. With format

`Monday, August 5, 2019 3:22:57 AM +00:00`

for each activity with method POST, there will be a token duration checking first. The logic for checking is if the `total = duration + createdAt` is less than `currenttime`, the request is permitted, if not the user will be ask for re-login.

I don't know how to start, i'm confused because the duration is in millisecond, and the createdAt is in dateTime. I dont know how to total both of them.

Comment: Start by correctly parsing "Monday, August 5, 2019 3:22:57 AM +00:00", see  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results) Then see [*Calculating the difference between two dates*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410285/calculating-the-difference-between-two-dates). You can just do `if ((dateA - dateB) > someValue) ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is what you are looking for

```
let curTime = new Date().getTime();
let createdAt = "Mon Aug 05 2019 10:00:12 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)";
let createdAtTime = new Date(createdAt).getTime();
let duration = 60 * 60 * 1000;
let expiryTime = createdAtTime + duration;

if (curTime < expiryTime) {
  console.log("Token is valid.");
} else {
  console.log("Token has expired.");
}
```